# Android Mapview Markers Delay

Tags: android, google-maps, xml-parsing, google-maps-markers, android-mapview

In my android app, with a Navigation Drawer, I have a problem with a fragment in which I use a mapview: when i launch the fragment for the first time, it shows only the first of one list of markers I want to draw. I have to reload the fragment to see all the markers draw on the map (or for example click on another voice on the menu and after again on the map fragment). I have the feeling that the fragment launch the map before all the markers are draw. Can it be the problem? How could I fix it? This is my code:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private MapView mMapView;
    private View mView;

    public MapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);
        return mView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mMapView = mView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        if (mMapView != null) {
            mMapView.onCreate(null);
            mMapView.onResume();
            mMapView.getMapAsync(this);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        drawMarkerOnTheMap(mGoogleMap);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        LatLng city = new LatLng(40.679425, 14.755968);
        CameraPosition camera = CameraPosition.builder().target(city).zoom(15).build();
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camera));
    }

    private void drawMarkerOnTheMap(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        try {
            InputStream is = getContext().getAssets().open("turisticpoint.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
            Element element=doc.getDocumentElement();
            element.normalize();
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("turisticpoint");
            for (int i=0; i<nList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nList.item(i);
                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element element2 = (Element) node;

                    String title = getValue("title", element2);
                    String tit = getContext().getResources().getString(getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(title, "string", getActivity().getPackageName()));

                    Double latitude = Double.valueOf(getValue("latitude", element2));
                    Double longitude= Double.valueOf(getValue("longitude", element2));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().
                        position(position).
                        title(tit)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
                    googleMap.addMarker(marker);

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
            NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
            Node node = nodeList.item(0);
            return node.getNodeValue();
    }
}
```

In my logcat I just found this error:

```
E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10063: Read-only file system
```

this is my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="package">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="MyApp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

and my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myappId"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 16
        versionName "1.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        missingDimensionStrategy 'minApi', 'minApi18', 'minApi23'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

and this is an xml file similar to mine:

```
<records>
    <turisticpoint>
        <titolo>Gardens</titolo>
        <latitudine>40.678480</latitudine>
        <longitudine>14.753152</longitudine>
    </turisticpoint>

    <turisticpoint>
        <titolo>Castle</titolo>
        <latitudine>40.6794731</latitudine>
        <longitudine>14.7544442</longitudine>
    </turisticpoint>

    <turisticpoint>
        <titolo>Beach</titolo>
        <latitudine>40.6965378</latitudine>
        <longitudine>14.7777038</longitudine>
    </turisticpoint>
</records>
```

in total I have 13 turistic point.

Comment: Are you still having this issue? If so, do you get any errors in your logcat and can you please share your (or a dummy) xml file and your manifest + build.gradle so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?

Comment: yes I still have it. Ok I will edit my post

Comment: the strange thing is that on the emulator everything work fine, but when I install the apk on my phone I see on the map only the marker with the first data, and the other 12 turistic point not. ut if I go to another place in the app and after I come back, all the marker are draw correctly.

Comment: I mean when I open Map Fragment for the first time I see only Garden (marker is displayed in the correct position and with title), for example, and only after reload Map Fragment I see also Castle and Beach markers

Comment: Thanks I see, so this only happens on physical devices? Which one have you tried it on? And does it happen across multiple ones or only the one? Also have you tried running your app in release mode with an emulator? In that case, do you get this issue, or does it work fine?

Comment: I was going to try to replicate your issue on my end but I can only use emulators so this complicates things. :/

Comment: I used a Samsung Galaxy S8...anyway I didn't find yet a solution :/

Comment: I see. Can you please try using a different android device? Since it works fine with emulator we need to determine whether the issue is specific to your device or not.

Comment: I had the opportunity to test it on a Samsung Galaxy s7 and there it works without any problem

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, this strongly indicates that the problem is with your Samsung Galaxy S8.